# Portable Roslyn Analyser C# vS2015 Team Foundation Server Nuget Package support

Tags: c#, tfs, visual-studio-2015, roslyn-code-analysis

I'm trying to write a basic diagnostic analyser with code fix (involving calls to TFS, work item create and update)

Target framework is .Net framework 4.5, ASP.Net Core  1.0, Windows 8, Windows Phone Silver light 8.

When I try to add a Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient, I receive the following error

Install-Package : Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient 14.95.3 is not compatible with .NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile78.
At line:1 char:1
+ Install-Package Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], Exception
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PackageManagement.PowerShellCmdlets.InstallPackageCommand

I also tried Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client and get the same error.

Any help to overcome this issue would be appreciated.

I also tried to change the target framework of the analyser project to NetStandard 1.5 by doing the below
1) Uninstall all nuget packages
2) Change target framework
3) Install package  NETStandard.Library 1.5.0-rc2-24027 
4) Re install Code Analysis package - failed here saying v1.22 of code analysis is not compatible.

Comment: Which version of TFS are you using?

Comment: Hi Cece. TFS version is 2013.

Comment: Hi @Cece-MSFT Is there a way I can use the tfs client object model .. i gues thats what I was trying and I am unable to find a nuget package that has Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.Client  and workitemtracking client dlls.

Comment: Tfs client object model is not compatible with .NETPortable application. If you are able to upgrade your TFS to TFS 2015, REST API will be a good option for you.

Comment: I have managed to change the project from PCL to CL and now can reference the tfs extended client nuget packages. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

The error message has indicates the error: Microsoft.TeamFoundationServer.ExtendedClient is not compatible with .NETPortable.

If you are using VSTS or TFS2015, you may try to use [REST API](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/integrate/api/overview).

If you are using TFS2010 or TFS2012, you may check [OData API](https://tfsodata.visualstudio.com/).

Comment: I will give OData API a go. Thanks